# Untar specific files in a specific directories and account for any error cases?

Tags: python, list, function, os.walk, os.path

I am trying to reduce the following code and possibly create one function that can be reused to untar files. Currently it does the following:

1. Traverse a directory and look in folders that are of the current year and month (YYMM*) "where * is don't care" and contain a specific file (example file.tar)
2. Test the folder and desired tar file to see if it has specific read/writing privileges blocked, if so generate a .txt file as a form of logging and do not allow duplicate references of locked files
3. With the files that are not locked (read/write denied) and contain the specific file I am looking for (example file.tar), untar the file and leave contents in the original folder
4. When untar is complete, remove tar file and leave tar file contents in folder

Currently the only way I could think of finding out whether the file/folder is locked is through hardcode values.

```
import os, re, tarfile
from datetime import datetime
dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
curr = dateTimeObj.strftime('%y%m.')
path = r'C:/Users/UserName/Documents/TestFolder/Folder/'
Path_to_example_tarfile_parent_list = [] #Defines list for example specific folders
RXList = []

def oswalk_directory(your_path):
    for directory_path, subdirectories, files in os.walk(path):
        for each_folder_name in subdirectories:
             #Add path+folder_name to end of each folder path
            for each_folder_name in subdirectories:
                Path_to_example_tarfile_parent_list.append(path+each_folder_name)
                #print (each_folder_name)
                if re.search('example_Logs', each_folder_name) :#Traverse directories specific directories that have example_Logs folder
                    Path_to_example_tarfile_parent_list.append(path+each_folder_name)
oswalk_directory(path)    
#Create a list of directories to traverse in current year and month:
print(os.getcwd())                           
print (Path_to_example_tarfile_parent_list)           
for i in range(len(Path_to_example_tarfile_parent_list)):
    #If a directory/folder has write permissions
    if(os.stat(Path_to_example_tarfile_parent_list[i]).st_mode == 16895):
        print("Checking file permissions RW = ok")
        
        for  directory_path, subdirectories, files in os.walk(Path_to_example_tarfile_parent_list[i]):       
            for each_folder_name in subdirectories:
                print ("Just before checking for example_Logs")
                if re.search('example_Logs', each_folder_name) :#Traverse directories specific directories that have example_Logs folder
                    isFile = False
                    print("If is not a file check")
                    print("Print path to file")
                    print (os.path.abspath(each_folder_name))
                    print(each_folder_name)
                    RXList.append((directory_path+'/'+each_folder_name).replace("\\","/")) #Append new list of folders to traverse, replace double slashes with single
                    isFile = os.path.isfile(directory_path+'/'+each_folder_name+'/example.tar')#Check if file exists in path

                    if isFile == True:
                        print("If is a file check")
                        if(os.stat(directory_path+'/'+each_folder_name+'/example.tar').st_mode == 33206):#Permissions for tar/archive file
                            #print (tarfile.info(root+'/'+each_folder_name+'/example.tar'))
                            print("Open tar file")
                            print(directory_path)

                            print(directory_path+'/'+each_folder_name+'/')
                            t = tarfile.open(directory_path+'/'+each_folder_name+'/')
                            for filename in ['example.tar']:
                                try:
                                    f = t.extractfile(filename)
                                except KeyError:
                                    print("Did not find tar filename")
                                else:
                                    print("Found file")
                            #tarfile.extract(directory_path+'/'+each_folder_name+'/')
                            #tarfile.extractfile(directory_path+'/'+each_folder_name+'/') #extract tar file contents to folder

                            tarfile.close()
                            print("Close tar file after extraction")
                            #os.remove(directory_path+'/'+name+'/example.tar')
                        elif(os.stat(directory_path+'/'+each_folder_name+'/example.tar').st_mode == 33060): #Else if: no write permissions, break
                            print("Break if file is not writeable")
                            break
                    else:#else, there is no example tar file
                        break
                                                  
    #If a directory has write permissions are denied                    
    if(os.stat(Path_to_example_tarfile_parent_list[i]).st_mode == 16749):
        print("If directory has write permissions denied then proceed to opening text file")
        found=False#Set found (duplicate indicator) to false prior to loop
        #Check to see if No_Write_Permission_Folder exists to store files with denied permissions 
        isFile = os.path.isfile(path+'tmp/No_Write_Permission_To_SIL_Folder'+curr+'txt')
        if isFile == False:
          f=open(path+'tmp/No_Write_Permission_To_Folder'+curr+'txt','w+')
          f.close
        else:
            with open(path+'tmp/No_Write_Permission_To_example_Folder'+curr+'txt', 'r') as Readfile:
                for line in Readfile:#For each line in txt file

                    if re.search(Path_to_example_tarfile_parent_list[i], line): #If current folder matches current line in txt file
                        found=True #Set found (duplicate) to True, matching line found in txt file 
                        break #terminate from inner loop
                if found == False:
                    with open(path+'tmp/No_Write_Permission_To_example_Folder'+curr+'txt', 'a') as no_write_file:
                        no_write_file.seek(0,0) #Set cursor to beginning of file to allow line-by-line printing 
                        no_write_file.write(Path_to_example_tarfile_parent_list[i]+'\n'.replace("\\","/"))
f = open(path+'/start_script.txt', 'a')
f.close()
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you asking people to minify your code in general? Are you asking how to check r/w permissions better? Are you just asking for people to debug your code?

Comment: Minify in general. Less hard coding of directory traversing, and permission r/w testing, error case testing.

Comment: As I am not as seasoned in this as most in Python

Comment: This sounds like it may work better as a bash script. Is Python a requirement? If so would you accept a python answer that uses `subprocess` to call a bash script?

Comment: When you mention you would like to check for `if it has specific read/writing privileges blocked`... could you rephrase this in the context of [Linux Permissions](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0090.php) and *Owner* / *Group* / *Public* ? Does that permission group need both read and write or is either ok?

Comment: Are all archives in `file.tar` compression or could they possibly by `file.tar.gz`?

Comment: file.tar. My current code can be simplified but I currently don't have the experience

Answer (score 0):

For your 'denied' files, use a `set` to store your file paths, instead of a file. You can write to a file at the end, or after you've collected a million directories or whatever but you probably don't need to

```py
my_set={'not_allowed_twice'}
my_set.add('not_allowed_twice')
my_set.add('this_is_fine')
my_set
```

To get a single function, use a recursive function to do the walk, instead of walking once and then looping - though it might be more elegant to appropriately split your logic out into however many functions are appropriate and then just use this code as a package with a single function interface like `untar_tree()`...
Here's your recursive walker:

```py
import os
def walk_it(folder):
 if os.path.isdir(folder):
  for f in os.listdir():
   if os.path.isfile(f):
    # do your logic here (is the file writable, if not, add it to a set)
    print(f)
   elif os.path.isdir(f):
    for f2 in os.listdir(f):
     # do your logic here (is the folder writable, if not, add it to another set)
     print("Keep on walking " + f2)
     walk_it(f2)
```

Don't worry about hard coding the file permissions, they are not going to change on your system. You could go for `stat.filemode(mode)` to convert the permissions into `-rwxrwxrwx` strings, which will make it easier to grok what's going on.

Comment: This would walk the directory with proper logic (locked/unlocked, specific name). Then I would need to add the text file to add any files that were locked (no duplicates allowed in txt file). Seems like a lot less code?

Comment: The first code snippet shows how to use a set instead of a file to store your deduplicated file list, the second is a single function to walk your directory hierarchy. Add your tests for file permissions, do your un-tar work where I've left the comments, and once the function is complete, use your sets to log to a file of deduplicated 'denied' files and folders

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in bash. I've marked up the script using your requirements as comments. I've tested this script on my end and it works well.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# 1. Traverse a directory and look in folders that are of the current year and
# month (YYMM*) "where * is don't care" and contain a specific file (example file.tar)
FILENAME="file.tar"
find -type f -iname "${FILENAME}" -newermt "$(date '+%Y-%m-')1" | while read F
do
    DIR=$(dirname "${F}")
    # 2. Test the folder and desired tar file to see if it has specific read/writing privileges blocked, if so
    # generate a .txt file as a form of logging and do not allow duplicate references of locked files
    if stat -c %A "$DIR" | grep -q 'drw.rw.rw.' && stat -c %A "$F" | grep -q '.rw.rw.rw.'
    then
        # 3. With the files that are not locked (read/write denied) and contain the specific file I am
        # looking for (example file.tar), untar the file and leave contents in the original folder
        tar -xvf "$F" -C "$DIR"
        # 4. When untar is complete, remove tar file and leave tar file contents in folder
        rm -f "$F"
    else
        touch "$F"_lock.txt
    fi
done
```

I am uncertain about two things that I did not gather from reading your question:

1. What Owner/Group/Public permissions are you looking to filter on? I've assumed `-rw-rw-rw-`
2. Are the tar archives compressed as tar.gz's or simply as tar files? If they could be in `.gz` format we'll have to change the `tar -xvf "$F" -C "$DIR"` line to include the `-z` flag

Comment: I would rather keep it written in Python. As far as permissions go rw for all. I was either trying to have it export to a .txt or csv and keep a log of files that can’t be untar’d. The script would search each folder for the specific file then move on through the directory of folders with YYMMDD format.